# Integers represented by the polynomial $a^2+b^3+c^6$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can every sufficiently large integer be written in the form $a^2 + b^3 + c^6 $ for some non-negative integers $a,b$ and $c$?

Comment: Please do not delete the content of the question.

Answer (score 18):

This is question 3 on page 146 of the second edition of *The Hardy-Littlewood Method* by R. C. Vaughan, with $b \geq 0.$ 

          
[image: Vaughan]

                <sub>(Image added by J.O'Rourke)</sub>

The answer is *No*, by a simple volume argument. It is not even necessary to know the exact constant, just that the number of lattice points with $x,y,z \geq 0  $ and $$  x^2 + y^3 + z^6 \leq N$$ is less than $CN,$ with a constant $0 < C < 1.$

I'm in question 5 on the same page.

Image hosting did not work. Please see: [VAUGHAN PDF](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Vaughan.pdf)

Oh, well. The relevant calculation is the sum of the reciprocals of the exponents, in case the polynomial is the sum of distinct monomials in the different variables. You might think that $$  x^2 + y^2 + z^9$$ ought to represent all large numbers with $z \geq 0.$ There are no local obstructions. But this is not the case. We can think of the exponent in this volume calcultaion as $10/9.$

It is reasonable to ask, how large an exponent reciprocal sum can we get and still fail to represent large integers? The best I have is $4/3,$ and in the simplest form we require coefficients, as in
$$  x^2 + 27 y^2 + 7 z^3.  $$ This is a version of the $ 4 x^2 + 2 x y + 7 y^2 + z^3,  $ which is more natural but looks less diagonal.

Comment: @Joseph, thanks. I bought a scanner for home, it is a nice flatbed that does one page at a time. Canon Canoscan LiDE 210. Of course I had to update Ubuntu to get it to run, which disabled my printer. It's always something. So I have been able to post stuff on MSE for months, sometimes line drawings i do, maybe book pages. I tried the same thing here. i thought I did it properly, but no image appeared. 

Comment: If I remember right there's a known example of a quadratic form
$ax^2+by^2+cz^2$ (so "exponent reciprocal sum" $3/2$)
and an arithmetic progression in which every positive term
is represented except the squares.  (Restriction to an arithmetic progression is the best one can hope for, because it's impossible for a ternary quadratic form over $\bf Z$ to be unobstructed for all positive integers.)


Comment: @Noam, Yes, of course. The prettiest example would be $3 x^2 + 4 y^2 + 9 z^2,$ which does not represent any $w^2$ where all prime factors of $w$ are $\equiv 1 \pmod 3.$ That goes back to Jones and Pall (1939). The proof is elementary, although now there is an entire industry dealing with the spinor genus and spinor exceptional integers, after Eichler. I guess I ruled those out automatically. A (probably) complete list is at http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/index.html#Jagy if you click on the word Table. 

Comment: Just to fill things in, for (positive) prime $q \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ there is an integral representation $ 3 x^2 + 4 y^2 + 9 z^2 = q^2.$ With $9$ itself, that settles the representation question for all squares. 

Comment: With prime $q \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ we may take $q = r^2 + s^2 + 3 t^2$ and, by choosing $\pm s,$ then demand that 
$ r \equiv s \pmod 3.$ Then we have
$$  q^2 = 3 (2 r t)^2 + 4 (rs)^2 + 9 \left( t^2 + \frac{s^2 - r^2}{3}  \right)^2.  $$


Answer (score 9):

The number of positive integer triples $(a,b,c)$ such that  $a^2+b^3+c^6\le x$ can be estimated from above by

$$x\int_0^1 \int_0^{(1-c^6)^{1/3}}\int_0^{(1-b^3-c^6)^{1/2}} 1 \, da\, db\, dc\, ,$$ 
that is $\theta x$ with $\theta <1$, so that a portion of integers with positive density is not representable.

Comment: The OP did not say that $b$ was positive...

Comment: Are you claiming that $a \ge n^{1/2}$, etc? Why?

Comment: Because I was wrong! 



Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that a,b,c are postivie!

Comment: (there is a more precis counting though, to fix the above argument )
  

Comment: Are you saying that a positive proportion of triples in $[0,x^{1/2}] \times [0,x^{1/3}] \times [0,x^{1/6}]$ have $a^2+b^3+c^6>x$? I guess that's clear.

Comment: It's easier than you think, see my answer.

Comment: exact. Indeed my first idea was a triple integral (then I oversimplified the computation)

Comment: See http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Vaughan.pdf  

Comment: The constant is $$  \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)   \Gamma \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)  \Gamma \left( \frac{7}{6} \right). $$ The technique for evaluating the integral is due to Dirichlet and is in the book by Whitakker and Watson.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. I suspected a Beta around. 

Comment: I wonder if the integral is also the density of the representable integres (meaning that multiple representations do not count so much)

Comment: Pietro, it may be the density of represented integers, hard to say. But from the example $x^2 + y^2 + z^9$ with $z \geq 0$ we know that is not the end of the story. In this case, by density all (large) integers should be represented quite often, but $216 p^3$ for prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is not represented, proof is elementary. 

Comment: Thank you. Also, not every integer is a sum of three squares, even though the exceptional set has $0$ density, right? Fascinating problems. 

Comment: Pietro, for the sum of three squares there is a local obstruction, you can never integrally (or rationally) represent anything $7 \pmod 8.$ There are no local obstructions for these other examples. So there are congruence obstructions possible, then there are factorization obstructions, finally (and very similar) there are class field theory obstructions, as in my very first MO question. After Kevin Buzzard's answer to that, the overall question becomes: are those all?

Comment: @Pietro Majer: The numbers which are not a sum of three squares are of the form $4^a(8b+7)$, hence their density is $\frac{1}{8}\sum_a 4^{-a}=\frac{1}{8}\frac{4}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$.